# Generate Link from Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a `GoogleMap` in my application. There are `PolylinesOptions` displayed on it. Is there a way to retrieve link. And when I type that link to browser it will display exactly the content I have I my application? Thanks

Comment: Can you help us explain this issue with a diagram? Initially you said that want to retrieve the link (of what?) and then you are able to get it and paste it in the browser. So what is the exact issue?

Comment: I want to share a `GoogleMap` in googlePlus ... but i didn't find any way so I thought that If  I could generate a link, I could share a link. But I don't know how to create a link with `PolylineOptions`